# sort - prepend each group that start with the same letter in sorted list with an arbitrary string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sort

Given the following list (input):

```
apple
banana
blueberry
mango
melon
```

I want the following output:

```
== A ==
apple

== B ==
banana
blueberry

== M ==
mango
melon
```

Is this possible to do in a shell script, perhaps with `awk` or some other text processing utility?

Comment: Please see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310) I'm voting to close this one. For the record, cross-site duplicate is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63852412/10765659

Comment: Sure, this post can be closed. I posted here first and got no answer so I went over to SO.
Thus this post is redundant at this point.

Comment: wrt `I posted here first and got no answer so I went over to SO` - we can see the timestamps and you asked the question on SO 9 minutes after asking it here. 9 mins isn't much time to give up on getting a response from a forum.

Comment: Tried deleting this question here but got: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it."  
I don't know what you guys want me to do, write a public apology?  
I posted the question here, waited 10 mins and saw 4 views, so I posted it on SO and got over 10 views within a couple of minutes and an answer.
I'm sorry for wanting eyeballs on my problem and for opting-in to getting an answer quicker? If double-posting is such a great concern of yours then please vote to delete this post, I'd already do it if I could.

Comment: To be clear: I wanted you to get familiar with the link I gave you (you seem to have done it); and to avoid cross-posting in the future (I believe you will from now on); nothing more. "Posted on multiple sites" is a standard community-specific reason to close a question here on U&L SE, I mean it's among few options a close voter can pick from. Other SE sites may not have it as an explicit option, one can choose "other" then. Therefore I conclude the reason is *especially* valid here and using it is by no means overzealous. Note: close votes are to close, not to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
awk -F '' '
   { if (NF != 0)
      { if (toupper($1) != c)
         { if (c != "") print ""
            c = toupper($1)
            print "== "c" =="
         }
         print
      }
   }'
```

Explanation:

- `-F ''` makes `awk` treat characters as fields. This works for sure in GNU `awk` (`gawk`). Other implementations may or may not support this. POSIX states "if `FS` is a null string, the behavior is unspecified".
- `if (NF != 0)` is responsible for ignoring empty lines. You did not specify this exact behavior, but I think it's the right thing.
- `c` stores the uppercase version of the previous first character.
- `if (toupper($1) != c)` checks if the uppercase version of the first field (i.e. of the first character) in the current record (i.e. line of input) differs from the stored value. This code runs for the first time when the first non-empty line is encountered. This happens before `c` is assigned anything and the condition is trivially true. For later lines it may or may not be true.
- `if (c != "") print ""` prints an empty line that will separate groups, unless `c` stores nothing which means no group has been printed yet. This way we avoid an empty line before the first group in the output.
- `c = toupper($1)` updates `c`.
- `print "== "c" =="` prints the group header you requested.
- `print` prints the current record (line of input).

Comment: Thanks for your solution.
A simpler solution can also be found for those interested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63852412/sort-prepend-each-group-that-start-with-the-same-letter-in-sorted-list-with-an/63852504